# Inserting 0.1 million records in Azure SQL Server is taking long time

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

I am trying to process an Excel document with 2 sheets. 1st sheet contains the meta data and the 2nd sheet the actual data.

The 1st sheet has 10 columns and the second sheet has a minimum of 50 columns & can vary. The process is before I push the data into the SQL Server database I have to validate each and every cell of the sheet. Some are just the data type validation for the sheet and some columns are needed to be validated against the database values and create the error object accordingly if failed.

On top of it the header sheet data has to be processed first followed by the actual data. The mappings for the header & data sheet are maintained in the database and are validated. Since there will not be more than 1000 records in the header I am processing and pushing the header data in the database in one go.

I am converting the data sheets columns as json object one for a row and then for every 5000 rows I am calling a stored procedure to insert these records into the database.

This whole process of validation, creation of error objects and pushing of the data for close to 0.1 million records is taking nearly 20 minutes of time.

Is there a way by which I can make it faster? In the future, we might get over 1 million of records in the sheet.

Since a lot of logic is also involved in stored procedure, the `SqlBulkCopy` option also seems to be not appropriate here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddData] (
    @Table DataTable READONLY,
    @DocumentType NVARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF(@DocumentType = 'abcd')
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (
                DMDId,
                SN, 
                Name, 
                Date, 
                GP, 
                D, 
                NP, 
                Data,
                IsLatest
        )
        SELECT 
                DMD.Id,
                PDDT.SN, 
                PDDT.Name, 
                PDDT.Date, 
                PDDT.GP, 
                PDDT.D, 
                PDDT.NP, 
                PDDT.Data,
                1
        FROM @Table PDDT
            INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 DMD
                ON DMD.TY = PDDT.TY AND 
                   DMD.TP = PDDT.TP AND 
                   DMD.IsLatest = 1
            INNER JOIN dbo.Table3 P
                ON P.CPID = PDDT.CPID AND 
                   DMD.PID = P.Id

    END


END
GO



 CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DataTable] AS TABLE
(
    [Id]                    [INT]               NULL,
    [SN]                    [NVARCHAR](50)      NOT NULL,
    [Name]                  [NVARCHAR](50)      NOT NULL,
    [Date]                  [DATETIME]          NOT NULL,
    [GP]                    [NUMERIC](22,2)     NOT NULL,
    [D]                     [NUMERIC](22,2)     NOT NULL,
    [NP]                    [NUMERIC](22,2)     NOT NULL,
    [Data]                  [NVARCHAR](MAX)     NOT NULL,
    [TP]                    [INT]               NOT NULL,   
    [TY]                    [NVARCHAR](20)      NOT NULL,   
    [CPId]                  [NVARCHAR](30)      NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to simply bulk insert the data, in it's raw format, into a staging table and then do the validation etc as it moves from the staging to production environment. Although the process is called "ETL" (Extract Transform Load), you find that "ELT" is just as common.

Comment: Also (impossible to know as we have no code), but I *assume* your stored procedure is transforming the data as a dataset, and not 1 row at at time (by means of a `CURSOR`, `WHILE`, etc). If not then switching to a set-based method from a iterative method will be almost certainly be huge time saver.

Comment: @Larnu Yes. I am passing the batch of 5000 records as table valued parameter to the stored procedure.

Comment: Passing as a TVF doesn't mean you aren't using iterative processes. :)

Comment: @Larnu I am trying to insert the records by applying the joins on the required tables and the passes table parameter using select

Comment: @Amit, what do you mean by "passes table parameter object using select"? It may help if you add relevant code snippets to your question, including the TVP type definition.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added the stored procedure logic.Please review.

Comment: @Amit, what about the TVP type definition and a snippet of the app code that loads the TVP? An important detail is the client provided meta-data should match that if the TVP type for best performance. Side note, avoid using `sp_` as a user stored procedure prefix as that is used to denote system stored procedures.

Comment: @DanGuzman Sorry. I missed that. I have again edited and provided the user defined table type definition. Also going forward I'll avoid using sp_ as a prefix. Thanks for the info. The data column is of type NVARCHAR with maximum length as this is the column which contains the row data of excel sheet as a json  string. I might not be able to provide the app code here as it is very huge.

Comment: Are you using a `DataTable` as the TVP source or some other object/enumerator? In the case of a `DataTable`, make sure the data types match that of the TVP definition, including maximum value length for the other string columns.

Comment: You say _This whole process of validation, creation of error objects and pushing of the data for close to 0.1 million records is taking nearly 20 minutes of time._... so which part of this process takes the most time? It might have nothing to do with the database.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have created a data model similar to the user defined table type, created a list object of that model and populated it with data and then just before passing that model object to the stored procedure converted it data table and then passed it to the sp.

Comment: @Amit, make sure the DataTable column metadata matches the TVP type definition as I suggested to optimize the passing of the TVP. Run this query get the proc execution time (which does not include the TVP transfer time): `SELECT min_elapsed_time, max_elapsed_time, total_elapsed_time / execution_count AS avg_elapsed_time FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'sp_AddData');`